Inertia of reduced symmetric real regular indefinite matrix
Given is a regular real symmetric matrix $\boldsymbol{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, with $m < n/2$ negative eigenvalues.
I wish to know: Is it always possible to extract a submatrix of $k=n-2\cdot m$ rows & cols of $\boldsymbol{A}$ that is positive definite?
I tried LDL pivoting arguments and min-max theorem derivates.
In fact, my interest is related to LDL. If I can assert what I wish to know then a certain pivoting strategy is successful. That pivoting would allow me to assert a desirable sparsity in my factorization, stable and maintainable with low-rank updates. This is not some homework assignment even when the question seems similarly innocent.
